# How to handle negative WACC due to net income of a company being negative?

Tags: wacc

I am calculating the weighted Average capital cost of a company using the following formula : [WACC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EM8RXNgyeLo&list=PLtaiPXYQc0W320LClqIJIunnlFQs8TOi7&index=8&t=197s&ab_channel=Dr.PhilHarris)

However the company I am tying to find WACC has negative net income.
As a result my WACC is negative.
How should I handle such a scenario?

[image: Financial Details]

Comment: You don't need income for WACC, also, you can't have a negative marginal tax rate.

Comment: How to measure the marginal tax rate then. Is it not tax paid / net income ?

Comment: I think that return on debt cannot become negative - else the entity is bankrupt, no?